# Are there any hosted services for Socket.IO (or alternatives)?

Tags: google-app-engine, comet, socket.io

I have a web application running on Google App Engine and need to provide near real time updates to connected web clients. One way would be to use the Google App Engine Channels API, but I'm a bit uneasy about using a proprietary solution.

Are there any reliable hosted services allowing for clients to connect using Socket.IO (with all its supported fallback protocols), and a web server solution running on Google App Engine to publish notifications to it? Any other alternatives that offers the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You looking for something like beaconpush.com?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you.
I've thought about using the Channel API as well however the free quota is quite low (100 channels created per day, each client is one channel).

Here's the solution I'm building:

All of the server logic runs in app engine python runtime

app engine serves all the html and client code

I run a node.js socket.io server on dotcloud (using their free tier)

the node.js server sets up an http server that listens to get requests on a few special url endpoints (ie: myapp-on.dotcloud.com/room/[room_id]) and when it gets called it triggers the socket.io broadcast to the appropriate clients

html clients generated on app engine connect to my myapp-on.dotcloud.com

All user input in the client is sent to app engine via a normal ajax post/get

when the app engine server code needs to push something to the client it makes a url fetch on the appropriate url (myapp-on.dotcloud.com/room/[room_id]) that triggers a message push via socket.io to the connected clients

I'm yet to implement this, but sounds like a workable plan
the idea is to keep all the logic in app engine and only use the socket.io server as a message pusher